# How to transfer an entire MongoDB collection to a web application?

Tags: mongodb, https, protocols, data-transfer

I'm currently trying to figure out a way to transfer a dataset stored in a MongoDB collection to the web browser, thus to store it into indexeddb asynchrnously via web workers, and for that, I was considering to build an API endpoint that would paginate the entire datasets and send it as JSON objects arrays to the client via API calls.

The data I need to send varies between 10kb and 5GB per collection.

Would there be a better way to achieve what I'm attempting, like sending binary data through protobuf;